# Red Black Tree and Multimap

Tags: c#, java, c++

In many compilers, Standard data structures like `Set`, `Map` and `Multimap` use Red-Black-Trees in behind, and a `multimap` stores multiple and duplicated keys.

I have a question about below quote:

> "A red-black-tree stores keys uniquely and binds just one DataValue to
>   each key"

1. Is above statement true?
2. If that is true, How we can use a red-black-tree to implement a `multimap` (as C++ STL did)?

Comment: Did you have a look at Wintellect's Power Collections http://powercollections.codeplex.com/ It includes MultiDictionary, OrderedMultiDictionary and an internal RedBlack class that they use on the OrderedMultiDictionary. By the way .Net's SortedDictionary is implemented using a red-black tree (SortedSet). You can find the source code here http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Nope, not true.

2) Modifying a single mapping red black tree to map keys to multiple values would be trivial.  It would just require using a second data structure and mapping key -> collection.

For example, instead of mapping from a string to and int, you could map from a string to a vector of ints.  Or a string to a linked list of ints.  Or a string to a single-mapping RBT. So on :).

---

Revisiting #1: Technically that would still be mapping a key to a single value, just the value wouldn't be the directly mapped type.  Depending on what you consider a "DataValue", then yes, the statement is true.

---

Also, the auxiliary data structure isn't actually necessary; it just simplifies traversal.  Basically to accommodate duplicates, instead of a strict less than/greater than relation between parent/left and parent/right, you have one of the sides also include equal.

For example:

```
      5
   3     7
 3
```

Comment: But, In c++ a `multimap` can store duplicated <Key,Value> pairs. For example If I insert <1,"First"> three times. The `multimap` has three of that same pairs.

Comment: Exactly. A multimap stores a data structure in each node which can hold multiple values. Note that binary trees are mostly about the *keys*, not the *values*.

Comment: Was just writing out a comment, but yup, Philipp nailed it :).

Comment: @Philipp: Yes, the question is that. How it has this functionality where it uses a red-black-tree?

Comment: A binary tree is organized by its **keys**. The keys in a tree which represents a multimap are unique. But in addition to the key, which is used to find the position of the node in the tree, every node also holds a **value** which doesn't matter for the tree layout. In a map, the value is a single variable. In a multimap, the value is a list of variables. You can think of a multimap<int, int> as a map<int, list<int> >.

Comment: I wonder why C++ has multimaps in its standard library. A `std::map<std::forward_list<E>>`/`std::map<std::vector<E>>` or a map with a comparator as you described seem like the same thing but with more control to the user

Answer (score 5):

You allow children on either side of a node to contain keys that are neither less than nor greater than the parent.  You need to allow equality on both sides because otherwise you can lose balance horribly --- a tree made from n equal keys will have height n.